# SQL Server - Query to append a text string to fields if they don't already contain it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2016 - we have a table with a column called Categories.  The contents of this column are any number of 5-character text strings, separated by commas.

Example:

```
  Categories
1 ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO
2 ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO, PQRST
3 FGHIJ, KLMNO
4 KLMNO
5 KLMNO, PQRST
```

I want to run a query that says, for any record that doesn't already contain ABCDE in the field, append it to the end of the field, of course preceded by a comma.

So the end results would look like this:

```
  Categories
1 ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO
2 ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO, PQRST
3 FGHIJ, KLMNO, ABCDE
4 KLMNO, ADCDE
5 KLMNO, PQRST, ABCDE
```

The following would also be acceptable...

```
  Categories
1 ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO
2 ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO, PQRST
3 ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO
4 ABCDE, KLMNO
5 ABCDE, KLMNO, PQRST
```

But it seems that would be a little tricker to structure the query.  The resulting order of the separated values is irrelevant, in any case.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your effort?

Comment: Storing CSV in column isn't a good idea.

Comment: @lad2025 this is not relevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] Int,[Categories] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO')
,(2,'ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO, PQRST')
,(3,'FGHIJ, KLMNO')
,(4,'KLMNO')
,(5,'KLMNO, PQRST')

Update @YourTable
   Set [Categories] = [Categories] +', ABCDE'
 Where charindex('ABCDE,',[Categories]+',')=0

Select * from @YourTable
```

**Updated Table**

```
ID  Categories
1   ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO
2   ABCDE, FGHIJ, KLMNO, PQRST
3   FGHIJ, KLMNO, ABCDE
4   KLMNO, ABCDE
5   KLMNO, PQRST, ABCDE
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two similar ways to do this, depending on what else you are doing with the data.

If you are already updating every row, you can use this to prepend the string.

```
SUBSTRING(CASE WHEN Categories NOT LIKE '%ABCDE%' THEN 'ABCDE, ' + Categories ELSE Categories END,1,LEN(Categories) + 5 )
```

If you only want to touch the rows that do not have the value, use `NOT LIKE '%ABCDE%'` in your where clause and then do a simple concatenate to add the string value to every row.

Prepend and Append both have to look for the extra comma, it just determines which side you have to look for it.  I preferred prepend in your example because it looks nicer.

Comment: Wes, your solution works too.  Thank you for the input.  John Campbell's query ran faster so I marked his as the answer.